# Nginx rewrite rule with 2 variables

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

i need simple Nginx rewrite rule to rewrite

```
/?contidion1=variable1&condition2=variable2
```

to

```
/variable1/variable2/
```

This one doesn't work...

```
rewrite  ^/condition/(.*)/([0-9])$ /?condition1=$1&condition2=$2  last;
```

Also tried:

```
rewrite  ^/condition/(.*)/(.*)$ /?condition1=$1&condition2=$2  last;
```

However condition with 1 variable working good

```
rewrite  ^/condition/(.*)$ /?condition1=$1  last;
```

Comment: The rewrites you tried attempt to do kind of the opposite of what you've asked. Could you disambiguate and clarify your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like this or exactly this:

```
rewrite ^/\?condition1=([^&]*)&condition2=([^&]*) /$1/$2 last;
```

First rule in `rewrite` means what pattern your url must pass to be rewrited to second`rewrite` rule. Next in second rule you can use parameter as `$1` and `$2` which correspondents to group in first rule (group is delimited by `(` and `)`)

If doing in other way, because your suggestion what you want to do are a little different from your rewrite rules, do something like this:

```
rewrite /(.*)/(.*) /?condition1=$1&condition2=$2 last;
```